# Unable to creating new route in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Codeigniter** after creating new Route in `Routes.php` when i am checking it on my browser it redirect me on the Home Page of my application

Code define in `route.php` is below:

```
 $route['ViewShan']='Member/Jammat/viewJammat';
```

URL Which i am checking is 
http://localhost/MembersPro/ViewShan

Comment: what is `viewJammat`? it is parameter passed to function or not.

Comment: it is a method inside controller Jammat

Comment: then what is `Member` ?

Comment: it is a directory

Comment: are you using HMVC?

Comment: no i am using mvc

Comment: check answer once...

Answer (score 0):

Change your routes

```
$route['ViewShan']='Member/Jammat/viewJammat';
```

to

```
$route['ViewShan'] = 'member/jammat/viewJammat';
```

Comment: all my previous routes are working properly in the pattren i am using but when i am create new i redirect me to home page

Comment: on change given by you by i am getting error page not found